# Passing a session variable to the table update stored procedure in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

How do I pass a session variable to the Insert, Update, Delete stored procedures mapped to a Table in an Entity Framework, and how do I get the mapping in the EDMX diagram to work with it?

I have a database with Stored Procedures (SPs) defined for Inserting, Updating, and Deleting rows. The SPs expect a userid parameter to be passed to them for audit trail purposes, this parameter does not exist as a column in the table.

When I'm in the EDMX diagram specifying the mapping for the Parameter I don't see any way to either a) ignore the parameter or b) (preferred) set the value to a Session value. I've created a partial class mapping of the Stored Procedures, however the model doesn't seem to see it or even acknowledge that it is there. The whole premise behind using this technology is to let it do the work. I can't even tell it to ignore this parameter as it is optional and has a value assigned to it. I can't even edit the SP definition as the file is marked autogenerated, and will lose any modifications when it is regenerated.

Entity Framework seems like a well thought out approach, and I've looked at several tutorials and books on the subject. However, this seems like a really obvious thing to do. I've looked through stack overflow and the MSDN forums and found similar questions from years ago, but no one ever seems to answer the question, they just dance around the issue.

Comment: Entity Framework isn't directly connected to ASP.NET - and thus doesn't know about ASP.NET session - and that's a good thing, in my opinion! You can always set the parameter values **in code** in your code-behind file - to anything you like, including values from the session.

Comment: I don't think you can add an extra parameter to a store procedure that is mapped to a CUD operation.

Comment: Wow, I find both of these statements disconcerting. I like that EF isn't directly connected to the .NET application. However, I should be able to include any "code resolvable" implementation in the mapped CUD operations. This is very basic functionality (IMHO) that other technologies (e.g., PowerBuilder) have been able to do for years.